# Regex for decimal values accepting zero but not blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, format, decimal

I need some help to create a regex for decimal values to be used in jquery, where:

Valid inputs-
- 0.1
- 1222.0
- 0.22
- 0.00
- 22.223

Not valid inputs-
- .1
- 1.
- 22.
- .234
- 0.
- .00
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

If I read your requirements correctly, a valid decimal is a number which has a decimal point, and one or more numbers on both sides of that decimal point.  If so, then the following regex should work:

```
^\d+\.\d+$
```

### Demo

Comment: Wouldn't it need to have `^` and `$` if validating that a whole string is valid?

Comment: @nnnnnn Some regex APIs apply the pattern to the entire string by default, and some don't.  I can never keep track of this.

Comment: I understand. JS doesn't in a general sense, but some validation libraries do.

Comment: Guys thanks a lot for your help. Making some tests I realised that the problem was caused because I was testing the regex with a decimal value and then it always recognises for example .1 as 0.1. Then transforming the decimal into a string did the trick. Ho by the way i used the following regex to get this result:   /^[1-9]\d*|0(\.\d+|0)$/;